# Setting the image path of CLR module in Windbg

Tags: module, clr, windbg

When I run the 64-bit version of Windbg on a Win7 64-bit machine, it shows the image path of the the `clr.dll` module to be the 32-bit version of the framework, not the 64-bit.

Is there any way to specify the image path for the `clr.dll` module in Windbg? Should Windbg 64-bit running on a 64-bit box be grabbing `clr.dll` from the Framework64 directory?

```
0:000> lmvm clr
...
    Loaded symbol image file: clr.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
```

I have a 64bit w3wp.exe dump that I cannot use SOS on, and I believe it's because of incompatible frameworks, caused by this 32bit clr dll image.

```
0:000> .loadby sos clr
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos) failed, Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."
```

Once again, the dump is from a 64-bit server, I've doubled checked that it has the same CLR version as my Win7 64bit machine I'm debugging on, and I'm running 64bit Windbg.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
...
Windows 7 Version 7600 MP (4 procs) Free x64
```

When I run 32-bit Windbg, it loads SOS fine, but then errors when I try to run `!threads`, with the ubiquitous `Failed to load data access DLL, 0x80004005` error.

Can the CLR image be set and if so, how?

Comment: Based on what you typed, the dump is very likely to be a 32 bit dump, not 64 bit as you thought. Keep in mind that a 64 bit process can never load a 32 bit dll such as the 32 bit clr.dll. Then you should see if @nithins's reply is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually sounds like an mscordacwks issue.  Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2009/02/18/failed-to-load-data-access-dll-0x80004005-or-what-is-mscordacwks-dll.aspx for an excellent guide on resolving this.

Comment: I think you're right @nithins, the problem is probably w3wp.exe running under WoW64 (I see wow64 using `~kb`). Windbg does seem confused about whether it wants AMD64 or x86 version of mscordacks. I'm not certain how to generate the dump with a 32bit debugger when on a 64bit machine though. 

Edit: Found it, [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx), should've searched harder first. Thanks for your help @nithins.